# What cell phone (with some qualifiers) has the longest battery life?

Tags: mobile-phone, battery-life

I am looking for a cell phone with very long battery life. I value long battery life so much that I am willing to sacrifice every feature **except** for:

- Basic calling/texting abilities
- *Modern* (**html5**) web browsing abilities (Must be able to play YouTube, Vimeo, check account balances, browse Wikipedia, etc.)
- Would like for it to at least be able to pinpoint my location and show it to me, but turn-by-turn navigation is not needed (i don't even use it when available as eyeballing the map is easy enough)
- Must be capable of <s>syncing</s> transferring photograph & audio files to and from Ubuntu

I do not care about the operating system or form factor as long as it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find several Androids with great battery life. The longest seems to be the **ASUS ZenFone 3 Zoom** ($319 [on **Amazon**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XW6SJF8)), Which Tom's Guide called in June, [**"Longest Battery Life Ever"**](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/asus-zenfone3-zoom,review-4367.html). And it is a pretty capable phone in every sense.

Something a bit more expansive and not as good battery life, but still above average, is the [**Blackberry -Android running- Key One**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06ZYGDY4P)

And at last, if this is such an important thing for you, just take some time and read some guides to familiarize yourself with all the ways to make sure to get out the most of the battery that you have. A guide like [**How to make your Android smartphone's battery last longer**](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-save-battery-life) from the good folks at **Android Pit** can help a lot! And you can even experiment with turning On **Battery Saver Mode** (usually turns On when the phone is low battery) the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

My Moto z is great, especially if you buy the battery mod attachment. It's big, and a bit heavy, but it usually lasts at least the day and into the next morning before I have to charge, depending on how much use it has (if it isn't used a lot, I'm sure it'll last quite a bit longer). I like this phone otherwise for the awesome camera, and decent interface.

Comment: Is it the best though?